# Minimal subset to cover all sets

Tags: python, set

We are provided with 5 different sets:

```
s1 = {a,b,c}
s2 = {c,d}
s3 = {a,g,h}
s4 = {d,e,f}
s5 = {g,k,l}
```

The goal is to find the minimal amount of items such that each set is represented at least once. In this case, we can easily see that the idea solution is `{a,d,g}`. Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Edit: this is what I have so far (`r` is the list of sets)

```
for i in r:
    i.sort()

r.sort(reverse=True)

arr = []

arr.append(r[0][0])

def isInArr(k):
    for j in k:
        if j in arr:
            return False
    return True

for i in r[1:]:
    if isInArr(i):
        arr.append(i[0])
```

Edit 2:

This code combines the answer of Connor and bruteforces the (to my knowledge) optimal solution.

```py
def isnotarr(k,rs):
    for j in k:
        if j in rs:
            return True
    return False

def most_frequent(List):
   return max(set(List), key = List.count)

##s1 = set(["a", "b", "c"])
##s2 = set(["c", "d"])
##s3 = set(["a", "g", "h"])
##s4 = set(["d", "e", "f"])
##s5 = set(["g", "k", "l"])
set_list = [set(i) for i in r]

return_set = []
while len(set_list) > 0:
   elements = []
   for s in set_list:
       for el in s:
           elements.append(el)
   element = most_frequent(elements)
   return_set.append(element)
   new_set_list = []
   for s in set_list:
       if element not in s:
           new_set_list.append(s)
   set_list = new_set_list

print "================initial set found============\n"
print(return_set)
print "================initial set found============\n"



def isvalidcomb(cm):
    for el in r:
        if isnotarr(el,cm):
            pass
        else:
            return False
    return True

def bfopt(n):
    combs = itertools.combinations(return_set,n)
    for i in combs:
        if isvalidcomb(i):
            return i
    return None

for i in range(len(return_set),0,-1):
    print "===========computing sets for maxlen %d============\n"%(i)
    tmp = bfopt(i)
    if tmp is not None:
        print tmp
```

Comment: what do you mean each set is represented at least once? Do you mean, so that at least one element from each set appears?

Comment: Yes exactly, that;s what I mean

Comment: [This](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3276/given-a-set-of-sets-find-the-smallest-sets-containing-at-least-one-element-fr) seems to be your question in a more computer-sciency way

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it.

```
def most_frequent(List):
   return max(set(List), key = List.count)

s1 = set(["a", "b", "c"])
s2 = set(["c", "d"])
s3 = set(["a", "g", "h"])
s4 = set(["d", "e", "f"])
s5 = set(["g", "k", "l"])
set_list = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5]

return_set = []
while len(set_list) > 0:
   elements = []
   for s in set_list:
       for el in s:
           elements.append(el)
   element = most_frequent(elements)
   return_set.append(element)
   new_set_list = []
   for s in set_list:
       if element not in s:
           new_set_list.append(s)
   set_list = new_set_list
print(return_set)
```

Answer (score 2):

First: each set can be represented by a power of 2: `si = 2^(i-1)`.

Each letter can be considered an item of weight 1 that has a certain value.

The value of a letter can be evaluated as the sum of the sets it represents.

e.g.: **a** represents **s1** and **s3**, so **value[a] = 2^(1-1) + 2^(3-1) = 3**.

Now your goals is to find the amount of itens with minimum weight such that the sum of its values is (1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16) = 31. This is basically the [knapsack problem](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-solve-the-knapsack-problem-with-dynamic-programming-eb88c706d3cf), a well known dynamic programming problem. Each item would be a letter and your knapsack has size 5 (at most). You need to get a value of 31 within this size.

As for the value of each letter, you can just preprocess.

Comment: This is very similar to the code I implemented below. The only difference is that instead of assigning each set a value based on a power of 2, I simply removed the sets from consideration once an element from that set has been added to the list. This way, you are simply counting occurrences of each element in the remaining sets each iteration.

Comment: I'm not very into python so I didn't examine the code deeply, but I wanted to state that this problem is a case of the knapsack problem as well.

Comment: Totally! Your answer adds a lot of value, I just wanted to connect it to my answer for anyone reading.

Comment: Connor's answer works very well, however it doesn't seem to find the optimal solutions for large amount of sets (n>10000).

Answer (score 2):

This is precisely the **[set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)**, a classic discrete optimization problem. It's NP-hard but there are many good algorithms for it, both exact and approximate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to pick an increasing number of items out of all distinct items and check if the picked set of items has at least one item in every set in the list:

```
from itertools import count, combinations
r = [{'a', 'b', 'c'},
     {'c', 'd'},
     {'a', 'g', 'h'},
     {'d', 'e', 'f'},
     {'g', 'k', 'l'}]
all_items = set.union(*r)
print(next(set(picks) for size in count(1)
    for picks in combinations(all_items, size)
    if all(any(i in s for i in picks) for s in r)))
```

This outputs: (Your sample input has more than one optimal solution and this outputs only one of them.)

```
{'c', 'd', 'g'}
```

If you want all optimal solutions, you can use `itertools.groupby` over the generator expression above with `len` as the key function:

```
from itertools import groupby
list(next(groupby((set(picks) for size in count(1)
    for picks in combinations(all_items, size)
    if all(any(i in s for i in picks) for s in r)), len))[1])
```

This returns:

```
[{'f', 'c', 'g'},
 {'e', 'c', 'g'},
 {'a', 'd', 'g'},
 {'b', 'd', 'g'},
 {'c', 'd', 'g'},
 {'a', 'd', 'l'},
 {'a', 'd', 'k'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to go about this, as I just learned. Essentially, each element is a `bool` variable and each set is a collection of `OR` constraints. Each set has to return `true` with the minimum number of elements set to `true`. This turns out to be very easily solvable by a linear solver like z3. Simply set the sum of sums of `true` in each set as the variable to be minimized and voila.